# Existe interfaces no python?

Tags: python, classes, interface

Em linguagens como PHP e Java, existem `interfaces`, que, quando implementadas em uma classe, obriga que a mesma contenha os métodos desta interface, da mesma forma que foram declarados.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
<?php

interace UserInterface
{
   public function getName();
}


class User implements UserInterface
{
    // Se eu adiconar um parâmetro, vai gerar um erro
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Scholl
{
     protected $users = array();
     /*
       Obriga a implementação de uma classe que implemente a 
        interface UserInterface
     */
     public function addUser(UserInterface $user)
     {
            $this->users[] = $user;
     }
}
```

Em Python, existe interface ou existe algum padrão para isso?

Se não existem interfaces, existe alguma maneira de "obrigar" que um método exista em uma classe?

Existe [indução de tipo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php) em Python?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Em python se usa [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), mas se você precisar obrigar alguém a implementar determinados métodos caso herdem de suas classes base você pode usar o [ABC (abstract base classes)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), mas isso não é muito comum (é mais comum para quem escreve frameworks).
Exemplo:

```
import abc


class Shape(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_to_implement(self, input):
        return
```

Caso fosse feita uma classe que herdasse de `Shape` mas não implementasse o método `method_to_implement` teria um `TypeError` por exemplo:

```
class Foo(Shape):
    pass

foo = Foo()
```

O código acima subiria a seguinte exceção `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Foo with abstract methods method_to_implement`

*Obs: em python 3.x a forma de declarar a metaclasse de uma classe muda um pouco:*

```
import abc


class Shape(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_to_implement(self, input):
        return
```

Outra forma é fazer como o @Pablo Palácios sugeriu, trabalhar com a exception `NotImplementedError` (o que é mais comum em aplicações corporativas).

```
class Shape(object):

    def method_to_implement(self, input):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Porém, nesse caso, o error só iria subir no momento em que o método `method_to_implement` fosse chamado.

```
class Foo(Shape):
    pass


foo = Foo()
foo.method_to_implement('bar')
```

Outra diferença é que o erro seria um `NotImplementedError` e não um `TypeError`.

Comment: A solução não funciona em Python 3.

Comment: @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes sobre a sua primeira pergunta (que aparentemente você apagou) sim, sobe uma exception, aqui está um exemplo http://pastebin.com/FeVZhAB7 mas note que esse código está escrito para python2

Comment: Sim, apaguei porque não fazia sentido uma vez que testei em Python 3. Aqui está o porque de não funcionar em 3 e uma base para funcionar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513821/python-metaclass-understanding-the-with-metaclass/18513858#18513858

Comment: É simples, é só mudar a base da classe `Shape` para essa syntax `Shape(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta)`, por exemplo http://pastebin.com/naYJc0iq

Comment: Ainda não apontando nenhuma excessão

Comment: Você viu o pastbin que mandei? O primeiro rodei no Python 2.7 e o segundo Rodei no Python 3.4, ambos subiram exceção...

Comment: Sim. Agora ficou muito bom! Você poderia editar sua resposta. Sua solução é mais rápida que a do @Pablo Palácios. UP!

Comment: Legal.. Vou incluir a forma do py3

Answer (score 9):

Python não possui uma sintaxe exclusiva para determinar uma interface. O que você pode fazer é construir um objeto que funcione como uma, pois, afinal, interface é um conceito e pode ser implementado de qualquer maneira.

Um jeito simples e rápido é utilizar a exceção `NotImplementedError` em uma classe pai:

```
class Animal:

    def andar(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Animais precisam implementar andar")
```

Dessa forma, para que a exceção não ocorra, todas as classes filhas de `Animal` precisarão implementar seu próprio método `andar()`:

```
>>> class Cachorro(Animal):
...     pass
... 
>>> c = Cachorro()
>>> c.andar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in andar
NotImplementedError: Animais precisam implementar andar
```

Note que Animal é uma classe como qualquer outra (sem nenhuma sintaxe extra) e, portanto, você pode fazer o que quiser com ela, inclusive colocar métodos não abstratos, constantes, etc... Isso pode ser bom para evitar uma arquitetura muito faraônica (interfaces + classes abstratas em java) se o seu problema é simples, como por exemplo, agrupar em um único lugar toda a lógica/valores/detalhes comuns a um determinado grupo de classes. Lembre-se, simples é melhor do que complexo.

Comment: Muto boa resposta - apesar de mais informativa, a  que cita as ABCs está "mais correta" - mas de repente você poderia só citar as mesmas ao final da resposta para fins de completude.

Comment: Desde que em python não existe diferença entre compiler time e run time, não considero essa resposta menos completa. Prefiro essa resposta, pois    é mais clara e prática.

Comment: Além disso a outra solução não funciona em Python 3.

Comment: Só salientando que a pergunta não especificava a versão do python.

Comment: A sua(@drgarcia1986) solução, se adaptar, fica melhor que essa porque essa solução não previne que a classe seja instanciada. Por enquanto essa solução está mais robusta.

Answer (score 3):

Muitos programadores Python afirmam que outros não precisaram de interfaces com Python - até eles encontrarem alguém que façam usar interfaces de qualquer forma (sim, existem pessoas que vão te obrigar a usar algo que você não queria, os *grandes chefes*).

As soluções acima resolve em partes, se você precisa de componentes do seu software seja facilmente plugáveis e extensível, existe um conjunto de pacotes chamado ZCA (*Zope Component Architecture*) que basicamente usam os pacotes *zope.interface* e *zope.component*, que facilitam o uso de Interfaces com Python.

Segue alguns links interessantes para o uso deles:

- http://muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html#marker-interfaces
- http://wiki.python.org.br/ArquiteturaDeComponentes

Comment: Sim, a ZCA pode ser muito útil em muitos casos,  principalmetne em aplicações realmente grandes.