# Implementar método abstrato em herança em Python

Tags: python, herança, classes-abstratas, pycharm

Seja a seguinte hierarquia de classes, onde a classe "A" tem um método abstrato chamado "foo":

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import abc


class A:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        return


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        pass 

    def foo(self):
        print 'Foo method in class B'


class C(B):
    def bar(self):
        print 'Bar method in class C'


def main():
    class_c = C()
    class_c.foo()
    class_c.bar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Esse código funciona perfeitamente, imprimindo o seguinte:

```
"Foo method in class B"
"Bar method in class C"
```

A minha dúvida é que o Pycharm diz que a classe "C" deve implementar todos os métodos abstratos, no caso os métodos definidos na classe "A".

Existe alguma convenção que diz que tenho que implementar todos os métodos abstratos? Existe algum problema em não implementar?

Comment: Eu posso quase garantir que é *bug* do PyCharm. C implementa todos os métodos de A. Só não é tão óbvio.

Comment: "C" herda de "B" que implementa o método abstrato "foo" de "A", mesmo assim não tem problema?

Comment: Não. Me parece uma ingenuidade do IDE. O importante é ter o método implementado. Só se tem algum macete no Python que eu desconheço (por isso não respondi) que cria alguma dificuldade. Mas não deveria existir.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Votei para fechar a pergunta como não repoduzível porque claramente era problema na IDE (ou má configuração) e não pode ser reproduzido apenas com o trecho de código. A classe C implementa todos os métodos abstratos através de B, então o problema não é em relação à linguagem.

Answer (score 3):

Talvez você saiba que esta forma não é muito *phytonica*. Quando você quer garantias no código é melhor usar outra linguagem. Este provavelmente é o motivo do PyCharm reclamar disto, ele não vai muito longe para verificar se está tudo em ordem.

Então ele não vê o método implementado ali e acha que é um problema. Não é, o importante é ter o método implementado, e foi na classe `B` e obviamente será herdado por `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Preciso discordar da opinião acima:

> Talvez você saiba que esta forma não é muito phytonica. Quando você quer garantias no código, é melhor usar outra linguagem.

Essa é uma grande confusão que muitos programadores Python realizam a cerca da linguagem e de como implementar certos códigos. O fato do Python ser flexível e não te obrigar a seguir determinados "padrões", não significa dizer que você não deva usá-los ou utilizar outras linguagens que "forcem" o uso do padrão, como Java, por exemplo.

No caso deste post, quando você utiliza a classe ABC como metaclasse de uma classe A, você está informando ao Python que todas os objetos que herdem desta classe A, devem "obrigatoriamente" implementar todos os métodos da classe A. Por isso, o Pycharm está reclamando.

Esse tipo de implementação é muito usado ao construir classes que implementar o padrão de "interfaces".

Caso queria mais detalhes você pode ver este link: [Existe interfaces no python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72685/existe-interfaces-no-python)