# Existem classes abstratas em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, classes-abstratas

Sou iniciante em Python e gostaria de saber se existe classes e métodos abstratos em Python, caso exista alguém pode me dar um exemplo? Quando estudei Java existiam essas classes pra criar um "modelo" e elas não eram instanciáveis.

Comment: Relacionado: [Existe interface em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72685)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim tem, [seguindo a documentação aqui do ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) precisa importar o ABC para criar uma classe abstrata:

```
from abc import ABC

class ClasseAbstrata(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method(self)
```

Nesse caso, o modulo ABC é como fosse "uma classe abstrata para criar classes abstratas"

Para herdar dessa classe:

```
  class ClasseDerivada(ClasseAbstrata):
     def abstract_method(self):
          print 'metodo na classe derivada'
```

Comment: Python suporta orientação a objetos e só adicionou o conceito de classe abstrata na linguagem numa atualização posterior? Essa eu não sabia, que "beleza" hein...

Comment: não entendi o "só adicionou o conceito de classe abstrata", não falei nada sobre o conceito, visto que isso não foi perguntado, só mostrei a implementação, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Fui nesse link e nele falava que esse suporte é uma PEP que foi adicionada ao Python, eu deduzi que fosse coisa posterior ao design inicial da linguagem. No meu ponto de vista em orientação a objetos baseada em classes o conceito de classe abstrata é essencial e uma linguagem que suporta esse paradigma deveria suportá-lo "na raiz". Foi só um comentário _en passant_.

Comment: ah sim concordo, nem deveria se precisar usar nenhum package, é um conceito básico de OOP, parece que foi um "puxadinho" :D

Comment: Vou falar com o Guido Von Rossum para resolver isso. :D :D :D ahahahah quem sou eu, ele deve ter tido suas razões. Tá lá explicado na PEP.

Comment: :D abre um incidente pra ele melhorar isso ;)